# Jquery return false not for sub-menu links

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

I have a rather simple menu stucture like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want the submenu to toggle on click of the main menu item. That works great like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul > li > a').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle('slow');
    return false;
});    

});
```

The 'return false' is to prevent the page from reloading on clicking the toggle-links. However: I want the submenu links to actually work as links. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You are sayling that this does not work as you want? It seems that it is what you need.

Comment: @Beri, it works, but because of the 'return false' the submenu links aren't linking to their respective pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('ul:not(:sub-menu) > li > a')
```

and you should be fine:)

Pwrsonally I would prefer to add top ul a class, but it will do also.

Answer (score -1):

Easy..

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Home</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul > li span').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle('slow');
    });    

});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tmprq7ur/1/

Comment: Thanks for your input, however, the main items have to remain links. They are generated by Wordpress. (I didn't give you the downvote btw)

Comment: Not sure what's up with the downvote. There's nothing wrong with this solution. An empty <a> tag is more incorrect than a <span> tag. However, if you can't change the HTML, use Beri's solution.